# React Map and Join from Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to map and join from the object below.

```
production_countries: 

0: 
iso_3166_1: "GB"
name: "United Kingdom"

1: 
iso_3166_1: "US"
name: "United States of America"
```

I tried `production_countries?.map((name) => (name.join(',')))` and it doesn't render.

I want the result to be `United Kingdom, United States of America`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't try it but I think this will work.

```js
production_countries?.map((item) => item.name).join(', ');
```

Because map will return array of only names then we join all elements of that array.

### Edit - Trimming the last space character

With above code you may end up having a space at the end of the string. You may call `trim()` string method to get rid of that.

```js
production_countries?.map((item) => item.name).join(', ').trim();
```